# VBA Macro to run PowerShell Command

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am trying to create a macro, that would be able to rename all files with ".docx" extension in a folder.

The PowerShell command works when used directly, but when used through the VBA code, it's not executing.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim retval
    Dim pscmd

    pscmd = "PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""Get-ChildItem -Path *.docx -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Substring(0,7) + $_.Extension }"""

    retval = Shell(pscmd, vbNormalFocus)

    Debug.Print pscmd
End Sub
```

The script is executing without compilation errors, but the files are not being renamed.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Your PowerShell `Get-ChildItem` command acts on the current directory, which it inherits from the calling application. Is that the right directory?

Comment: Can you provide the command line that runs directly in Powershell ? and how do your filenames look like?

Comment: and why not use the shell/command prompt, why only powershell to rename the file extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the path where your files exist
Try this and change the path to suit you

```
Sub Test()
Dim retval, pscmd

pscmd = "PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""Get-ChildItem -Path " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Files\" & " *.docx -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Substring(0,7) + $_.Extension }"""
retval = Shell(pscmd, vbNormalFocus)

Debug.Print pscmd
End Sub
```