# Create proceds macro using VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access

I am trying to create a macro that will allow me to access multiple switches and run the backup config commands on each switch. I can do so by using plink.exe using Putty.
We have CMD.exe blocked, but PowerShell isn't.

Since, I already have my switch table in MS Access and know a bit of VBA, I decided to create a macro that will launch PowerShell and issue the commands. My first roadblock was that trying to initiate a WScript.Shell object to open PowerShell gives me an "Access is denied" message.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run("PowerShell.exe")
```

I tested with calc.exe instead just to test and it opens fine.

Even though any user can open PowerShell and run commands. I *can* open PowerShell manually as any other user without issues.

Not sure what other way I can go about it.

I would have to type each commands and would like a way to read back the output to do some error handling.

I am accessing via SSH using a user and password, not SNMP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, this is an X-Y problem. This way of automating PowerShell is obviously blocked on purpose, on a normal machine your code runs just fine. Get sufficient permissions to not be blocked instead of trying to bypass security measures. That being said, you could go full WinAPI, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output for hints.

Comment: I concur with @ErikA, if your employer don't want users running `powershell.exe` by default and you have a legitimate use case that warrants an exception, then you should probably just _ask your IT/Security admin for an exception_, they're in a better position to help you do this securely than a bunch of random people on the internet are :)

Comment: I **CAN** run PowerShell. I said the command prompt is blocked but **NOT** PowerShell. I get access denied if I try to open PowerShell with Wscript.Shell object. I can open PowerShell and run commands. Any user can. I updated my OP as it apperently wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your IT/Risk Management/Polciy/Security folks are blocking macros as well. So, back to what Mathias, has said to you. Windows executables (ping, nslookup CScript, WScript, et al.), call cmd.exe period this do not run in PowerShell and can't. They call cmd.exe under the covers. You can use the Trace-Command cmdlet to see what is happening when you call an external executable from PowerShell.

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {
    # code to be traced here

} -PSHost
```

When you run this in PowerShell, you'll get a lot if process info and errors, because  VBA specific stuff is not recognized by PowerShell. Yet, this is just to drive home the point of what you are trying to do.

In PowerShell to use WSCript.Shell is as a object.

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell 
    $Output = $wshell.Popup("The task has finished")
    $wshell.Run('powershell.exe')
} -PSHost
# Results
<#
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [New-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Wscript.Shell] to parameter [ComObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ValidateTrustedDataAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Wscript.Shell] to param [ComObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [New-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [New-Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
0
#>

# That zero means, powershell.exe started successfully
```

If you are trying to use PowerShell to run macro say in Excel (which means you know PowerShell, how to call COM via PowerShell and know the DOM of your target), then that is stuff like this...

```
# start Excel 
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application  

# open file 
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ExcelWorkbook.xlsm' #<------- Change this!!! 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)  

# make it visible (just to check what is happening) 
$excel.Visible = $true  

# access the Application object and run a macro $app = $excel.Application 
$app.Run("Macro") #<------- Change this!!! 
$excel.Quit()     

# Popup box to show completion - you would remove this if using task scheduler 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell $wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x1)  

exit
```

You'd do similar stuff to create a macro to run later.

What you are doing is trying to use a macro to run PowerShell from whatever MSOffice DOM you are using, and that will call cmd.exe by default first before trying to start PowerShell.

If you are simply trying to run PowerShell code from the macros, then this is potentially a duplicate question, similar to this SQ Q&A.

[VBA Macro to run PowerShell Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956136/vba-macro-to-run-powershell-command)

***Update to my comment regarding***

> Why do this macro thing at all?

You say you are allowed to run PowerShell, just do it all from PowerShell.

Use PS to read MSAccess...

```
function Test-DBAccess
{
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('tdba')]
    Param
    (
         $fileName = 'D:\scripts\test.accdb'
    )

    $conn            = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$filename;Persist Security Info=False")
    $cmd             = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table1"
    $conn.open()

    $rdr             = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $dt              = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
    $dt.Load($rdr)
    $dt
}
```

Use PowerShell and Plink for Linux remote management

```
$PlinkPath      = 'D:\Tools\plink.exe'

$linuxhostname  = 'SomeRemoteLinuxHostname'
$linuxusername  = 'LinuxUserName'
$linuxsession   = 'LinuxSessionName'

# Some command
($GetIptablesNat = & $PlinkPath -load $linuxsession 'sudo -s iptables -L -nv --line-numbers -t nat')
```

Comment: I understand that some commands run on CMD, I CAN run ping, IPconfig, nslookup, etc within PowerShell. When running cmd I get the message `The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.` I am trying to run a macro type instruction set (not really an Excel Macro) by calling from MS Access VBA to run PLINK.exe and start sending commands. I mentioned PowerShell, because it is not blocked. I ran the `Trace-Command` you mentioned and get the same exact output.

Comment: I tried running the Shell command via VBA, but get `invalid procedure call or argument` error message.

Comment: Trace-Command only tells you what's on the stack so you can look back and see what is really happening good and bad. If your admin has blocked cmd.exe and cmd.exe gets/needs to be called in anyway, then the expectation is a failure by the policy. Not by the OS or PowerShell. So, again, back to Mathias said. You are literally asking this community to show you how to circumvent/violate your organization's risk policies. Even if we could the moment you'd get caught doing this, it could end up as an RPE for you. (Resume Producing Event). That's your risk though, if you choose to try to do this.

Comment: My comment about Excel was just a comment regarding how to do such calls with PowerShell, not that you were running any MSOffice product, but you did say you are using Macros in MSAccess. You can use PowerShell to read your MSA DB directly. Yet getting back to plink/putty, you can call those directly from PowerShell. I do this all the time to my linux-based stuff. So, why use this macro approach at all? Use PS to read MSA DB, call plink commands from PS.

Comment: I can run the plink application within PowerShell. I am just trying to automate connecting to my switches and running some commands to back them up. I have a query set up in Access with the switch IPs, user name and Password to setup connection as well as the switch name that will be the backup file name for each switch.

Comment: You can automate this by using PowerShell Jobs, WorkFlow techniques, and/or even scheduled tasks.